# R: Convert list of character dates to "days since" a given origin

Tags: r, date, netcdf, julian-date

I need to generate a list to attach as a time dimension for a NetCDF file. This file was stacked from many files that were generated as monthly means from 6-hourly data. As a result, each t observation is simply the chronological value of the file in the stack.

First, I generated a date sequence, converted it to characters and then created a date object stating the origin to be the origin of interest. My objective was to receive an integer list of "days since 1850-01-01", however, converting to an integer, I see the origin used is still the R default "1970-01-01".

I am new to working with this "Julian" approach and I would appreciate any advice as to what methods I should use.

The code is as follows

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("1901-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 12)
dates <- as.character(dates)

o <- as.Date("1850-01-01")

dates <- as.Date(dates, origin = o)
dates
dates <- as.numeric(dates)
```

Comment: Why using something so complex? Why would simply calculating the difference in time (for example using difftime) not work?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This also works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `dates` to `Date` class, subtract `o` and convert that to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.Date(dates) - o)
## [1] 18627 18658 18686 18717 18747 18778 18808 18839 18870 18900 18931 18961
```

Alternately convert both to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.Date(dates)) - as.numeric(o)
```

or use `difftime`

```
as.numeric(difftime(as.Date(dates), o, unit = "day"))
```

Comment: Thanks a million. That works perfectly. Also thanks d.b for the heads up on origin.

Comment: For the record, I get the same result using julian as follows: julian(dates, origin = as.Date("1850-01-01"))